# reCaptcha v3 forcing a bad score for testing

Tags: testing, recaptcha

Using the Google ReCaptcha v3. Is there a way to force a bad score from the site verify step `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify`?

I have the verification code all set up and working. It returs a score of 0.9 every time currently.

How can I make a bad score to return? I want to see the error message and user flow I have coded in if someone has a bad score.

I have searched a lot and there is no clear answer on testing the google ReCaptcha v3 for low scores. Seeming no mention of forcing a low score for testing.

So far I have tried a  number of user-agent strings, VPN to out of my country and submitting the form via console to remove the mouse movements. Nothing affects my score.

Has anyone managed to achieve this or is there another way I should be testing the `/siteverify` step?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came across this question in pursuit of the same answer, and just wanted to say my dummy solution was to just set up a variable called myScore and set it below the threshold you’re setting. This’ll give you the error response you want in order to work out the UI.

Comment: Thanks @M Pigs. Yes your solution will give me what I want to test. Given that no other solutions have come up this is the only way to test it for now it seems. Thanks for your input.